# How do you change core.autocrlf when using SmartGit?

Tags: git, smartgit, core.autocrlf

I don't have any experience with version control from the terminal but as far as I can tell SmartGit does not have a terminal nor does it use an external git client that I could configure via terminal so I don't really see how I can execute git configuration commands on it. Specifically, I want to do:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Does it have an equivalent configuration option available from within the UI or is there some other way to apply this?

Comment: Doesn't msysgit set this option by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SmartGit/Hg uses the command line Git which is configured in the Preferences. Both, command line Git and SmartGit/Hg will honor the global `core.autocrlf` configuration from your `.gitconfig` file.

Answer (score 9):

If you have problems with terminals, you could also edit the file $HOME/.gitconfig on Linux platforms or C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.gitconfig on Windows, and add the following lines to it:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
```

Also you can set the default EOL with:

```
[core]
    eol = lf
```

Answer (score 0):

When we select an item **Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style** during git installation, this setting is saved in "C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig" as `[core] autocrlf = true`